# How to change direction of label in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a label that read it's data from DB.(the data is date in Persian language.).
By default it show LTR but I wanna write it RTL.
for more info:
it show :01/05/1999
but I want to show it:
1399/01/08
How do it?(with Javascript,jQuery or that is better to CSS)
Notice:I don't have any problem with convert Persian date to Gregorian Date.

Comment: ? is "1399/01/08" the reverse of "01/05/1999" ??

Comment: I don't see that either is LTR or RTL are you talking about formatting according to a specific culture?

Comment: Do you want to change the date as well ?? or it should show as 1999/05/01 ?

Comment: @DavidePiras ,Hi.It's not important for me to reverse the date!just wanna show it to my custom direction.("1399/01/08 is a Persian date" and "01/05/1999 is a En date")

Comment: @RMN ,you understand well! I wanna show 1999/05/01

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways. Programmatically, you can add a `dir` attribute

```
myLabel.Attributes.Add("dir", "rtl");
```

or in the `HTML` itself as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twe16yc2.aspx).

```
<asp:Label dir="rtl" >
```

As per the comments, the date being reversed like that is not `right to left` formatting. RTL is for when the letters and numbers are in the invariant order, but the sentences themselves are written from right to left.

Answer (score 3):

Create a CSS class such as

```
.lbl_rtl
{
  direction:rtl;
}
```

and then

```
<asp:Label CssClass="lbl_rtl" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do two things
* Format the output according to a specific culture
* Set the direction of the label as well

```
//format the date string according to persian culture 
var dateString = date.ToShortDateString(new CultureInfo(“fa-Ir”));
myLabel.Text = dateString;
//set the direct to right-to-left
myLabel.Attribute.Add("dir","rtl");
```

if you have the need to set rtl on a lot of elements you should prefer to do this using css.

```
.rtl {
   direction:rtl;
}
```

would set the direction for all elements with a class of `rtl`

Answer (score 0):

salam,baraye inke kolan covert koni bayad code c# estefade koni ama baraye rtl kafie direction ro rtl koni,ham code barat mizaram ke miladio tabdil koni be shamsi,ham style

```
.lblDirection{
  direction:rtl;
}
```

baraye codet ke tabdil kone

```
public string SetShamsiDate(string DateTimeLoc)
        {
            DateTime DT = DateTime.Parse(DateTimeLoc.ToString());
            System.Globalization.PersianCalendar pc = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
            string DaySprated = pc.GetDayOfMonth(DT).ToString();

        }
```

hala mitoni mah ya sal ro begiri

You want use this style for direction

```
.lblDirection{
  direction:rtl;
}
```

and for convert miladi date to persian calender use this code

```
public string SetShamsiDate(string DateTimeLoc)
        {
            DateTime DT = DateTime.Parse(DateTimeLoc.ToString());
            System.Globalization.PersianCalendar pc = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
            string DaySprated = pc.GetDayOfMonth(DT).ToString();

        }
```